# How to block attempts for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: web-server, asp.net, http-status-code-404, web-crawler

I converted my website from asp.net to .net core and host on same server. Now, website gets hundred of hits daily from different IP's trying to access like below

`/php-myadmin/
 /wp-content/
 /mysql/`

None of these directories exist on my website, I don't even have phpmyadmin on my server. I am logging error email if path is 404 not found on my website.

I would like to stop them if possible as I am getting hundred of unusual error email in a day. Also, I've blocked a handful of these IPs but they keep coming back with fresh IPs, is there any way I can prevent this more permanently? Or there is any way not to send email in that case?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Internet; every web server gets all kind of probe requests, mostly for these administration interfaces and paths for web applications with known vulnerabilities.

Therefore, it might not be a good idea to enable email notifications for 404 errors at all. Instead, in order to remove all the duplicates, you could either analyze the logs or save unique 404 URLs in a database. This way you can mark these as false positives and find possible actual problems way more efficiently.

Comment: No I am not gonna to save these into db. Can you please suggest me way where I can recognize these type of url and not to send email ?